# How to add tiny 0.5A 120V load to very remote split phase 240v 3 wire well house

Tags: electrical, wiring

Given that I don't have neutral, sounds like, even for just running a simple irrigation controller, that I don't want to use the ground wire for my neutral and simply pull 120v off the split phase 240V since a potential short would energize the ground wire.

It seems like running a small transformer is the way to go.  However often recommendations I have found mention adding a sub panel breaker after the transformer, which seems like overkill for my need.  Would adding a 5A fuse to new transformed 120V be fine instead of a whole breaker box?

I'm surprised how much transformers are, and most of them are for transforming single phase Euro 220v to US 110v, anyone have a good source?

As an aside, if this existing ground to the 240V did connect directly to ground at the main panel instead of neutral (haven't looked yet, in the neighbor's panel) then to me it would be ok to just pull L1 and ground off the 240V and skip the transformer right?  These are very large wires running a 20A load to a well pump, might 1000' away, so I think this is the only load on that breaker.

Comment: What are you trying to power?  It may well be easier to modify the device to accept 240V power than to try and get 120V in the building.

Comment: Also there's nothing wrong with using a transformer meant for travel within the US.  This one, for example, might do nicely for you: https://www.amazon.com/Power-Bright-VC1500W-Transformer-converter/dp/B000MWAKVU?th=1

Comment: @NateStrickland right on about changing the load!  The problem with those autotransformers is they will provide an approximate center-tap but it's not a bona-fide neutral, so both wires will be hot.

Comment: What is the load?  Will it be plugged into a receptacle or hard wired?

Comment: if it is just for an irrigation controller, then maybe all you need is  an appropriate 240VAC transformer ..... probably one with a 24VAC output ..... something like this .... https://www.ebay.com/itm/Transformer-40-VA-Rating-120-208-240VAC-Input-Voltage-24VAC-Output-Voltage-/273517667157 ........... or buy a controller designed for 240Vac ..... https://www.ebay.com/itm/Hunter-X-Core-220V-230V-240V-Outdoor-Controller-Xcore-Timer-4-6-8-Stations-Zones/280827014142?hash=item4162982bfe:m:mEwuYcOT0w7oRTp2E79WR4w

Comment: It is for an irrigation controller with 0.5A max, I want a specific new kind that has wifi access - https://bhyve.orbitonline.com/ , it takes 120vac. I was a little scared off the euro auto transformers when I saw some brands specifically mention NOT for US 240 conversion. So yes, still wondering about neutral as @harper said.

Comment: I looked ta the amazon link again, itself actually says "Intended for European 220-240V and NOT for US 220V"

Comment: Just to sanity-check here, does the irrigation controller *actually* have a 120V power input? And if so, is it listed for multi-voltage 120-240V (or 100-264V, or 100-306V or whatever)?   Or is it a "wall-wart" or "power brick" which actually supplies low voltage to the controller proper?

Comment: @Harper, it does take real 120V input, and it's got a transformer inside because it supplies 24V output.  However, it is sold overseas and listed for 240V there, so there's almost certainly a way to reconfigure it to use 240V here -- see my answer below.

Comment: Just for completeness, If I did find that the well ground going back to the 70A breaker (max load from the pump is 19A, only thing on circuit) went straight to ground in the panel that I could simply just pull off the incoming lines for my 120v?  I guess that does put the well pump controller case at risk of being energized during a short...of course if there is a short it will pop the breaker.

Comment: And to clear up something else, I assume the reason the manufacturer of the euro transformer mentions not for US 220/240 is that there is no neutral and the unsafe condition that can present during a short.  It was hard finding 2-3kVA transformers I was thinking about at first that aren't these Euro type.

Comment: Have you tried talking to your local supply house about a dry type distribution transformer in the 1.5kVA class @farmtech?

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead with the double transformer option with a back-up of opening the US controller up to see if a 240V conversion is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 0.15A x 120V, this thing is about 18 VA (similar to watts).   That is significantly less than 40 VA.

As it happens, 40VA thermostat transformers are cheap and common as dirt, typically around $13. **They make them with both 240V and 120V primaries**. Get one of each.

You connect the two 24V secondaries *to each other*.  The 240V primary goes to the 240V main via a 1 amp fuse.  The 120V primary feeds your controller.   This is double-isolated from 240V, so it won't be terribly dangerous.

If you really want to, you can call it a separately derived service and add a neutral-ground equipotential bond to whichever leg of the 120V you want to call "neutral", but given that it is going straight into another transformer that will *also* isolate it, that seems like much ado about nothing.

I recommend to snip the plug off the cord and hardwire this thing, to avoid the temptation of someone plugging a circular saw into the outlet.

Wow, that was easy and cheap.

Comment: This is the best answer if it's not practical to reconfigure the controller to take 240V directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm a little unclear on what you mean. Although may be getting it. So connect them in series but reverse polarity? Kind of genius. so 240v>24V>24V>120V? So polarity will not matter to my controller? Thanks also for catching the 0.15A max input, I saw 0.5A max load, but that was the output at 24V DC.

Comment: Looks like two of these will work? https://www.amazon.com/Packard-Control-Transformer-Class-Mount/dp/B01HPJT7C0/ref=sr_1_8?crid=8FB9I2CTO0FB&keywords=transformer+240v+to+24v&qid=1553887310&s=gateway&sprefix=transformer+240v%2Caps%2C382&sr=8-8

Comment: @farmtech, yes, that will work.  On the 240V input transformer, you'd connect the white and orange wires to the supply, connect the two transformers' red and green secondary wires, and on the output to your device you'd use the white and black primary wires.  Transformers can step up or down just as easily, so you're just stepping down from 240 to 24, then stepping back up from 24 to 120.

Comment: Doesn't the wire distance of how far you're going to run the 24 volts matter?For example if you're going to have a 2 volt voltage drop over that distance, it's going to drop to 22v which only gives you 110v instead of 120v when you transform it back up. Compared to if you ran it as 120v the whole way you'd have 118v instead.

Comment: @Dotes -- this is a "back to back" configuration with only inches between the two transformers

Comment: The load is also factored into voltage drop.  for example a 3 watt LED probably would not care,  but 40 watts might be a little much.  The back to back configuration minimizes voltage drop.

Comment: Also polarity doesn't matter unless your feeding DC, which if you were you'd need a full wave rectifier to stabilize the wave output

Comment: See my comment in the other answer. Swapping internal transformer.

Comment: Just to finish this up, The rewiring inside the timer was going to be a little tricky and void the warranty so I sent 240v (one leg is fused at the well, also installed a digital submeter to monitor total well electric use - so cheap!) 550' over 18 ga wire, transformed to 24 V ac then back to 120V ac, getting 123 V ac, timer works fine, valves actuate! This only works since my current demand is tiny BTW. Thanks all.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find 18AWG wire that was cheaper than 14AWG wire, I've never been able to do that.  Anyway don't let your inspector find this, I'm pretty sure 14 is the minimum for branch circuits.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific irrigation controller you linked, there's almost certainly a way to configure it to accept 240V directly.

From the [international manual](https://bhyve.orbitonline.com/site/uploads/2017/08/Multi-language_web.pdf) on their website:

> Rated input:
>
> Australia—240V AC 50/60Hz 0.15A
>
> Europe—230V AC 50/60Hz 0.15A
>
> USA—120V AC 60Hz 0.15A

I'd recommend contacting them to see if you can plug the one you have into 240V directly, or if there's some internal wires or jumpers that need to be reconfigured first.

Comment: This would be best of course, thanks I missed that!  I will call.

Comment: I called any they couldn't me with anything internal of course.  But they did say I could buy from the UK, just no warranty support in the US then.  I bet I could reconfigure, but gambling on that one for sure.

Comment: It is almost triple the cost from the UK.....

Comment: If you want to try reconfiguring it yourself, and can post pictures of the inside, we may be able to help.  But if you'd rather not bother and/or you'd like to keep your warranty intact, Harper's answer will be the way to go.

Comment: Great, I think I'll go in between and order them all and post pics and can return the transformers if needed. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Good plan.  It's very likely that the device actually has one of the exact same type of transformer you're ordering already inside it (since it has 24VAC outputs), with a similar system where you hook up to different wires depending on whether you're feeding it 120 or 240.  They probably aren't helpfully labeled, but with a multimeter you can often figure out what's what.  Or, if it only has 120V inputs, you may even be able to replace the transformer with one of the two you bought, and return the other one.

Comment: yes turns out it is a pretty normal power brick inside the case, although luckily it is openable so I can just swap out the transformer.  Inside is a 120v to 26VAC 0.75A transformer, so my 240 to 24V transformer I bought will work fine!  That probably helps my voltage loss issue too by transforming at the timer (550' away on 16 ga wire) instead of at the well house.  I do need to run a seperate ground at the timer since I only ran 16/2 cord.

Comment: Forgot to add this video I found - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXYNfx4o2r8

Comment: @farmtech Yeah, that's standard.  Easier to get UL to approve a low voltage device bundled with an already-approved power brick.  Anyway you are saying you put 240V on #16 wire for 550 feet??? Wow, that's even bolder than me, I use #14w/gnd for that.  Not having a ground in the long wire is super bad -- you need either a) ground in a parallel cable, b) GFCI, or c) isolate it electrically (just use the same 2-transformer trick I discussed in my answer).

Comment: I hear ya about the long run, but was assuming initially that it would be 120v.  It is only 0.15A so think it will be ok? Thoughts on still transformer to 24VAC and running 550'?

Comment: Edit- Thoughts on still transforming to 24VAC and running 550' instead of 240v for 550'?

Comment: So 0.15A at 120V means 0.075A at 240V or 0.75A at 24V.  16 AWG Cu wire has a resistance of about 4 ohms/1000ft, (and you have to count there and back, so 1000 feet is about what you have).  So we can use Ohm's law to find the voltage drop in the wire: Vdrop = IR.  At 24V, that's .75A * 4 ohms, or 3 Volts drop, so you'll only have 21V to work with at the end of the wire, a 12.5% drop.  At 240V you'll drop 0.075A * 4 ohms = 0.3V, so you'll have 239.7V at the end of the wire, well under 1%.  So 240V is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Nate, I should have done that calc myself...I think I was going off a recommendation somewhere, but that probably was for valve actuation, which presumably is more flexible than what the timer electronics wants.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this comes up all the time in industrial applications.  For example there may be a three phase 480V supply to a motor, but you need lower voltage for the controls.

The usual solution is a control transformer.  These are modestly priced, especially for tiny loads.  For example one brand, Hammond, makes control transformers as small as 50VA for under $50. (USD)

Take a look at this document from Hammond for wiring diagrams for various primary / secondary configurations:

https://www.hammondpowersolutions.com/files/HPS_Instruction_Sheet_Control_Transformer_WiringDiagram_PHWD1.pdf

With these products, there are fuse holders built in, and you can also buy enclosures ready made for the device for a finished install with minimal fuss, and there are enclosed versions that are built in an enclosure - lots of options.